# Access SQL Query product of 2 columns from different tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update the `[Table1].[Field2]` with the product of `[Table1].[field1]` and `[Table2].[field2]`.

Here is my SQL statement so far (I'm getting a *"too few parameters expected 3"* error)

```
Update [Table1] Set [Table1].[Field2] = [Table1].[Field1] * [Table2].[Field2];
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `[Table2].[Field2]` and `[Table1]` ?

Comment: There is a field3 that relates the 2 Tables. The field is unique on table 2 and is short text type.

Comment: Oh: there is no enforced referential integrity.

Comment: can you just print screen your table structure

Comment: just did, I edited it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Field2] = [Table1].[Field1] *
    (SELECT [Field2] FROM [Table2] WHERE [Field3] = [Table1].[Field3])
```

Comment: I'll test it now, give me a second.

Comment: Sorry for the wait... I'm still getting the too few parameters error. Since I am new to Access SQL I think I'm doing something wrong, even though I'm not sure what.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I'm still getting a too few parameters error (expected 2).

Comment: Try it again please.

Comment: I updated the question with exact code I'm implementing. Would you please take a look? (I've checked it and rechecked).

Comment: @jony My first answer should have worked, at least it would work on most RDBMS.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: join expression not supported... (FYI: I'm on excel vba connecting to an access .mdb database...)

Comment: @NewbeeDev Well, not yet... :( This seems like such a simple thing. I just need to multiply the elements of a column by another, it sounds simple, "sounds" being the key word. :(

Comment: Show your exact database structure.

Comment: How exactly? Print screen of relationships? Print of design view?

Comment: I added a printscreen of the relationships, is that the info required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123660/discussion-between-jony-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in access itself.........look at Darren Bartrup-Cook's proposed answer,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Access isn't most RDBMS (my wages would be much higher for a start). :)

You need to perform the joins first:

```
UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field3 = Table2.Field3
SET Table1.Field2 = Table1.Field1 * Table2.Field2
```

Comment: I went with a workaround (a slower method for sure, but not sure how much slower): pulling the data into excel spreadsheet columns A and B, autofill column "C" cells with `=A1*B1`, setting column C.values = column C (to get rid of the formulas and keep the values). That should work while the data is less than ~1.000.000 records long.

Comment: I'll try your solution and mark your answer as the correct solution if it performs as expected.